# Can Clone my Git Repository but can't commit and push

Tags: eclipse, github, github-for-windows

This is the error message I get when I put in my GitHub account info (it is the right login)

I can clone my repository but cannot commit and push

Can't connect to any repository: https://github.com/andrewl15/DLLProject (https://github.com/andrewl15/DLLProject: not authorized)

Comment: I don't see any error message. Just a link to your repo.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your folder ? if no! your folder project should have an document/html file  e.g `index.html` by convention for web server can be configured to recognize any file you want as the default for that site.

it's still a good idea to stick with index.html because it is immediately recognized on most servers without any additional configuration needed.

does this solves your error?